# Need to log storage type of local variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks

In short, I need to know if I am able to log the storage type for a variable.

Specifically, I want to log whether a variable has the `__block` storage type modifier applied to it.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
NSLog(@"storage type: %@", [localVar storageType]);
```

In case you're wondering, I think I just figured out a memory leak I've been debugging for the past few days, and I want to test if my assumption is correct.

I'm using ASIHttpRequest with `setCompletionBlock` and `setFailedBlock`, but I'm passing my request object to a convenience method that does the actual setup of the blocks, like so:

```
- (void)getAllHighlights:success:(ASIBasicBlockWrapper)cb1 fail:(ASIBasicBlockWrapperFail)cb2{

    // blah blah blah

    __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [self executeAsynchronousRequest:request onSuccess:cb1 onFail:cb2];
}
```

Then, `executeAsynchronousRequest` sets up the Blocks and starts the request:

```
- (void) executeAsynchronousRequest:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request onSuccess:(ASIBasicBlockWrapper)cb1 onFail:(ASIBasicBlockWrapperFail)cb2
{
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        int statusCode = [safeRequest responseStatusCode];
        NSString *statusMessage = [self statusErrorMessage:statusCode];
        cb1([safeRequest responseString],statusMessage);
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        cb2(safeRequest);
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];    
}
```

My hunch tells me that even though I set up my request object as `__block ASIFormDataRequest *request`, when it's used within `executeAsynchronousRequest`, it's lost the __block storage type since it has only been typed as `(ASIFormDataRequest *)request`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you aren't modifying `request` in a block, so `__block` isn't going to do anything for you... if you were passing in request to a block, it wouldn't be copied, it would keep the locally scoped version when you passed it into the block.

Comment: hmmm...if i "recast" my request object inside executeAsyncRequest like so: __block ASIFormDataRequest *blockSafeRequest = request; and then use blockSafeRequest within my block, all my memory leaks pertaining to ASIHTTPRequest go away.

Comment: setCompletionBlock and setFailedBlock do an explicit copy of the block. could this have any impact as to why casting the request argument with __block is successful at eliminating the leaks?

Comment: if you are just trying to track down leaks, have you used the static analyzer yet?